# Memory is not reclaimed when close the rocksdb instance

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

our project use rocksdb with [rocksdbjni](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.rocksdb/rocksdbjni) that is nice and easy to use.
but, some problems give me a headaches. when i close the rocksdb the momery in used doesn't properly reclaimed. It seems to depending on OS.

so i did some test with [this code](https://github.com/donggyu04/rocksdb-m-reclaim-test/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/org/rocksdb/example/RocksDbProcessor.kt) in macos and centos. test is simple, just compare memory changes when multiple rocksdb are opened & closed. the result is below.

memory not reclaimed on centos. if you know anything about this, please give me some advice.

- macos(pm)

[image]

- centos(vm)

[image]

Comment: without any code - there is no way to tell if your bench marking is correct. You are running this in a jvm? and printing out how much jvm memory is being used after all the rocksdb instances are closed?

Comment: @AsadAwadia you can bench marking test code in here https://github.com/donggyu04/rocksdb-m-reclaim-test/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/org/rocksdb/example/RocksDbProcessor.kt I ran this code on jvm, It doesn't seem to use much jvm heap but much of native memory was used

Comment: The memory left is what is being used by the jvm to run your code